# Disable Stemming on Query Parser

Tags: parsing, solr

I am using stemming in my Solr, but I don't always want to apply stemming for each search. I am thinking of disabling stemming on one specific query parser, can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to have stemmed and unstemmed searches, you'll need to define different fields in your `schema.xml` for the same content and simultaneously index the text into them (perhaps using [CopyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields)). One field should have stemming analyzers and the other should not.

Then, your search would specify which fields to search in.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.. actually i tried that option , but we are finding if we can do it on query parser and do not add extra indexing for copy field... but at last copy field will be the solution. Do you have any idea if we can do it on query parser or not?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. If you stem the content during the indexing you are actually losing information. You need to index it in another non-stemmed field. The same goes if you need to have exact matching respecting other types of analysis: case, diacritic removal, etc...